# Get the authenticated user with marionettejs and nodejs in frontend

Tags: node.js, express, backbone.js, marionette, passport.js

My question : **How to print the authenticated user's username in the layout in backbone ?**

I am using a stack with : NodeJs, Express, MongoDB and BackboneJs (with MarionetteJs as framework).

I can create and log in a user with passport and a steam strategy which stores the user in `req.user`.

This is an extract of my express server file which shows how I put the authenticated user in a middleware :

```
// use passport session
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});
```

But I don't know how to access this var in front with backbone. It's not really clear in my mind. Don't hesitate to ask more needed code in comments.

Comment: Your frontend app should send a request to backend, backend should respond with user data, when frontend receives it, display it in ui. Which part of this you're having a problem with..?

Comment: Maybe I have a conceptual understanding problem. But a request is sended to my server, it does its job and render my backbone home page. Backbone controller get it and render the different regions. Why can I not have access to the `res` object which contains (or not) the logged in user ?

Comment: You can't directly access stuff you have at server side from client side... You can only access  the data you send to client side using the response object, not the object itself

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user in a Backbone model, and you want the fetching to fit the Backbone paradigm, you could create a route that will send the user information to the front end.

**Server**

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.params.id === 'me') {
    res.json(req.user);
  } else {
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Invalid user id' });
  }
});
```

**Front end**

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/user'
});

var user = new UserModel({ id: 'me' });
user.fetch();
```

Then you can just create a regular ItemView and render the user information where you see fit.